# Django query object.values() list as parameter

Tags: python, django, django-orm

I currently have a query that looks similar to this:

```
Account.objects.filter(id__in=id_list).values("id", "first_name", "last_name")
```

Is there a way to pass a list into the values?
I've tried this

```
value_list = ["id", "first_name", "last_name"]
Account.objects.filter(id__in=id_list).values(value_list)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can unpack your list in `values` function.

```
value_list = ["id", "first_name", "last_name"]
Account.objects.filter(id__in=id_list).values(*value_list)
```

Here is [article](https://medium.com/understand-the-python/understanding-the-asterisk-of-python-8b9daaa4a558), if you want read about it.

Answer (score 1):

The argument to `values` are individual field names, not a list of field names.

You can use *splat*-ing to unpack the list:
`Account.objects.filter(id__in=id_list).values(*value_list)`